# One generic event name or multiple descriptive event name

Tags: c#

Would you do:

```
this.btSomeButton.Click += btSomeButton_OnClick;

private void btSomeButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DoFunc1();
    this.DoFunc2();
}
```

Or:

```
this.btSomeButton.Click += DoFunc1;
this.btSomeButton.Click += DoDunc2;
```

Are there any hidden implications for using the second method? Like, is it guaranteed that DoFunc2() will run after DoFunc1()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first method is safer.

AFAIK there is no guarantee when it comes to method execution order, and if the methods do come in a sequential the first method makes more sense anyway.

Also, when multiple event handlers are attached to an event, it becomes very easy to miss out other events when detaching individual event handlers.

Comment: While execution order is guaranteed (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx), it's still clearer to use the first method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the first as well..

Perfomance should be very close to the same in the 2 examples, but #1 is easier to read imho - however, it sorta depends on what they are doing. I'd prefer this for example:

```
this.btSomeButton.Click += DoSomethingRelatedToDataPersistence;
this.btSomeButton.Click += DoSomethingRelatedToTheDirectionTheMoonSpinsAroundTheEarth;
```

.. I hope you catch my drift :P

If you can tie the 2 event-handlers into 1 common procedure (talking from a domain-perspective) i'd do that. If the handlers are completely un-related I'd keep them in different handlers..

The answer is very subjective imho. No one will be able to provide a "final answer, case closed"-kinda answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the first if only for the reason that it's conventional practice, so clearer to other developers. Event handler juggling is hard enough to trace down in any case, so give everyone as much help as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

I would use second option if all (or most) below are true:

- DoFunc1 and DoFunc2 are completely independent of each-other in terms of functionality.
- Order of call does not matter (even in case of exception etc).
- DoFunc1 and DoFunc2 have no signature issues in receiving standard event parameters.
- DoFunc1 and DoFunc2 are not primitive functions in context of design.
- Different regions of source code may decide how many subscribers are needed.
- DoFunc1 and DoFunc2 are part of other class which is needed to be decoupled.
- I want to do custom processing when DoFunc1 and DoFunc2 are subscribed or unsubscribed.

If Order is important, first option is must as it is clear. I do not know if C# language spec guarantees order in second option.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I get the question.  This is a question about [Multicast Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx).  According to the docs ...

*A MulticastDelegate has a linked list of delegates, called an invocation list, consisting of one or more elements. When a multicast delegate is invoked, the delegates in the invocation list are called synchronously in the order in which they appear.*

If you care about the ordering of the calls, however, I wouldn't rely on this and I would use the first method or the method below.

You can do both if you like the syntax, but want the functional abstraction of both calls ...

```
this.btSomeButton.Click += (sender, args)
{
  this.doFunc1();
  this.doFunc2();
};
```

Comment: I think this is semantically equivalent to first option with btSomeButton_OnClick made anonymous.

Comment: Yes, but has the anon delegate and lambda syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first option, for a single (subjective) reason.

This is much more descriptive, and easier for other people to understand later.  This becomes important if the event is one where people will need to unsubscribe later - having a single event that needs to be unsubscribed is more likely to be handled properly by other people in teh future than 2 events.

Since you asked about order of execution, this suggests that the 2 functions are related.  Doing this forces the event to be unsubscribed together, so it wouldn't be possibel to unsubscribe from func1() and not func2(), which is likely very critical if you're worried about order of execution (which, btw, is guaranteed).